# Can one rely on rounded irrational numbers?

Tags: halacha, number, mathematics

Chazal often talk about irrational numbers in their math discussions. For instance, Sukkah 7b-8a uses both √2=1.4 and π=3 in its discussion, and Eiruvin 76a-b uses the same numbers in an almost identical sugya. And the list goes on.

But can we actually rely on such sources? That is, halacha l'ma'aseh, can we assume that π=3 for the sake of halacha? For instance, in the aforementioned sugya in Sukkah, discussing a round sukkah. If I actually wanted to make a round sukkah, can I take a 7x7 tefach square, multiply the side by 1.4 to get the diagonal of length 9.8, then multiply by 3 to get the circumference length of 29.4, and that would be a kosher sukkah? Or do I have to get as close to 7π√2 as humanly possible?

Comment: I remember learning about the yam shel shlomo in which the diameter and the circumference are mentioned with Pi equal to 3. Rashi goes through the calculation and shows that the shape is actually a cylinder resting on a square base so that the values do not round pi to 3.

Comment: It is Gemara in eruvin

Comment: @sabbahillel π(r^2)h + lwh = 3(5^2)(2) + 10(10)(3) = 150 + 300 = 450 = (3*1*1)(150). The numbers only work if you round π to 3.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the numbers are because the diameter is not actually the full side of the square. This would mean that the edge of the cylinder made is inset a little either because of construction or the thickness of the metal of which it is constructed. I think that Rashi calculates it using geometrical calculations and fractions. Using the exact value of pi, the  actual diameter would be 9.54929 amos to get a 30 amah circumference. Also, it is possible that the calculation was accurate and the measurement of the actual side was rounded up to 10 or circumference rounded down from 31

Comment: Another point is based on the description in [Melachim Alef 7:24](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15891#showrashi=true) and 7:26, the rim was flared. There are those who say that the cylindrical portion was flared and the rope around the circumference had to be under the flared portion of the brim.

Comment: @DonielF Rashi  on [I Melachim 7:24](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15891#showrashi=true) and 7:26 sayst that the calculation was based on the volume that the yam held (2,000 bat liquid and 3,000 bat dry) rather than the calculation by pi. Also given the square part of the (lower) section of the yam, the estimate for the upper (ciylindrical) part used the ratio given in Eruvin 14b (ArtScroll 14b1 note 8). This rounds Pi to 3 for ease of calculation rather than the exact amount because underestimating the amount of water in a (kosher) mikvah would not hurt.

Comment: Somewhat related - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81752/5275

Comment: 1. You ask and accept your own answer? Boooo. 2. I don't understand your reasoning before I start criticizing both the Q and the A. 3. Rabbis had no idea of Pi only mentioned that the circ. is 3 times longer than the diameter. 4. Please define "rely". I think the Q is not about relying but about their "knowledge".

Comment: @Al 1. That's old news; you can accept your own answer after two days of posting it, but you don't get any rep for it. 2. What would you like me to clarify? 3-4. π is the exact value of the ratio of the circumference to the diameter, and 3 is the value Chazal assigned to it. Whether they knew of its imprecision or not is irrelevant to this question; since *we* know it's off, are you allowed to rely on this approximation anyway? By "rely" I mean "Halacha X is based on assuming π=3; does that mean we still hold of Halacha X as written, or does it change based on advances in mathematics?"

Comment: Please show me a Halacha that actually USES Pi and calculations at all. I assumed there's no idea of a *mathematical constant* in Halacha.

Comment: @AlBerko Any context in which π is referenced - a circular *koreh* for a Mavoi (Eruvin 13b), a circular window between courtyards for Eiruvei Chatzeiros (Eruvin 76a), a circular Sukkah (Sukkah 7b-8a), etc. Likewise √2 has a few applications as well. So the question is: The Gemara concludes, for instance, that a circular Sukkah, according to Rebbe's opinion that a Sukkah must be 4x4 amos, must have a circumference of 16.8. Since we know π and √2 are more precise, should we build such a Sukkah to be 4π√2 in circumference instead?

Comment: Sorry, where do you see a reference to Pi? Where does it say - there's a magic and constant number that represents the ratio etc? It says (https://www.sefaria.org.il/Eruvin.76a.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) if the width is so and so and if the circ. is so and so. I don't see Pies here.

Comment: @Al The magic constant number that represents the ratio, according to the Mishnah, is 3: כל שיש בהקפו שלשה טפחים יש בו רוחב טפח. We know that this magic number is actually π, slightly larger than 3. Therefore, I ask: can one rely on Chazal's statement that the circumference is actually three times the diameter, rather than the actual measurement of π times the diameter? I didn't think it was such a complicated question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91914/discussion-between-al-berko-and-donielf).

Comment: That gemara in sukkah uses the phrase לא דק over and over again. לא דק has the מספר קטן of 3 1 4 1... a much closer approximation of π

Comment: @Daniel Interesting; I’d never heard that before. However, I was taught that מספר קטן rolls over at 10, not 9, which would give לא דק a מספר קטן of 2 1 4 9; was I taught incorrectly?

Comment: @DonielF Everything I can find online says mispar katan just truncates the zeros on the numbers. So 30 -> 3 and 100 -> 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be three mainstream opinions in the Rishonim and Acharonim.

## Only if you're not planning on cheating someone

The Sefer HaChinuch (Mitzvah 258) says explicitly that one may not rely on such estimations by Choshen Mishpat. In his words:

> ותזכר...שלא אמרו זכרונם לברכה על הכיוון כי אם בקירוב, ולכן אל תסמוך בזה בחלוקת הדברים בין בני אדם. ואל תתמה איך יכתבו דבר בלתי מכוון...ובזה מה שלא כיוונו בו מביא אותו לידי חומרא ואינו מזיק לכל אדם בממנו.
>
> And remember...that [the Chachamim], may their memory be for blessing, did not say [these previously stated mathematical principles] precisely, but were only estimating, and therefore, do not rely on this for separating things between people. And do not wonder, "How could they write something imprecise?" ... And on this that which they were imprecise would lead someone to act stringently and would not harm a person with his money.

The Shulchan Aruch (CM 231:16) and Rambam (Geneivah 8:1) say the same thing, that people are very careful with their money, and they don't want to part with it that quickly. They are quoting a Gemara in BM 91a; if anyone wants to argue with this opinion, they have to be more stringent. And indeed, they are.

## Only if you're dealing with π

The Maggid Mishnah in Hilchos Shabbos (17:26) says that one may rely on π=3, but he says in Hilchos Eiruvin (3:2) that one may not rely on √2=1.4. What's the difference? Perhaps it's because the former has a passuk (Melachim Aleph 7:23; see Eiruvin 14a) while the latter doesn't.

The Sha'alos U'Teshuvos Tashbeitz (1:165) gives two explanations of these estimations: either they're Halachos L'Moshe MiSinai, or they're there to help explain the sugya better and one may not rely on them. The first side clearly holds like the Sefer HaChinuch, Shulchan Aruch, and Rambam, but perhaps the second side agrees with the Maggid Mishnah that one may not rely on √2=1.4 but can rely on π=3. Or maybe that side agrees with the even more stringent opinion below.

## Absolutely never

In the aforementioned sugya in Eiruvin 14a, the Gemara opens up with the cryptic line: "How do we know [that the circumference of a 1-tefach circle is 3 tefachim]?"

Um, how do we know? Take a tape measure! (Or at least take a string, wrap it around a circle, and compare it to a ruler, or three fists lined up next to each other.)

The Tosfos HaRosh explains: Since π≠3, how do we know we can rely on this halacha l'ma'aseh? The Aruch HaShulchan (OC 363:22, YD 30:13) explains: Since π=3, the diameter is less than 1. How do we know we can make the mavoi permissible to carry in anyway?

These seemingly similar explanations could be arguing about this very point. The Aruch HaShulchan, who emphasizes the permissibility of the mavoi, would seem to hold that one may not rely on these estimations whatsoever. The Tosfos HaRosh, who asks how we know we can rely on π=3 but is silent about √2=1.4, could hold like either of the above opinions.

R' Moshe Feinstein (Igros Moshe, YD 3:120:5) asks whether one is obligated to use a microscope and other scientific tools to make his tefillin as square as possible. R' Moshe paskened that as long as one's tefillin match the 1:1.4 ratio mentioned by the Gemara, it's okay. He quotes a Brisker who implies that ideally one should not rely on such estimations, but technically it's okay. R' Moshe concludes in astonishment of how such a gadol like the Brisker Rav could possibly have said such a thing.

As they are discussing √2=1.4, it seems clear that R' Moshe holds like the above Shulchan Aruch, and while me'ikar hadin the Brisker agrees, ideally he would like you to hold like the Aruch HaShulchan.

## TL; DR

CYLOR.

## The longer TL; DR

- The Sefer HaChinuch, Shulchan Aruch, Rambam, one tzad in the Tashbeitz, R' Moshe Feinstein, technically the Brisker Rav, and maybe the Tosfos HaRosh all allow you to rely on π=3 and √2=1.4 as long as you're not dealing with Choshen Mishpat.
- The other tzad in the Tashbeitz and maybe the Tosfos HaRosh allow you to rely on π=3 by non-Choshen Mishpat but not √2=1.4 even by the other three areas of halacha.
- The Aruch HaShulchan and ideally the Brisker Rav prohibit relying on these estimations.

Comment: `He quotes a Brisker` Was it the Brisker Rav? Someone else quoting him? Not him at all? Consider clarifying.

Comment: +1 i usually don't like these types of question+ answer combos, even though it's completely acceptable, but this is very nice. I was keeping an eye out to see if you mentioned that Reb Moshe. Btw mevaqesh's issue with your phraseology is spot on. Struck me as weird.

Comment: @mevaqesh I don't have his exact lashon in front of me, but he says he heard in the name of the Brisker Rav and doesn't believe he actually said it.

Comment: @user6591 here is the original: 
ולכן כתבתי שהוא פלא מה שאמר אחד שהגרי"ז הלוי זצ"ל היה סבור שיש מעלה כשימדדו ריבוע דתפילין במיקראסקאפ, אך אם הוא אמת יש אולי לתרץ דחשש שמא עושי הבתים לא טרחו כפי יכלתם למדוד היטב שא"כ ליכא אף מדה דהאינשי, שהם אף שא"א לצמצם והתורה הכשירה כל היכא דמצית למעבד הרי צריך למדוד כל היכי דמצי בכל הטירחא וראיית העין שאפשר, ולא יוכשר כשיתעצלו לטרוח ולעיין היטב שזה הא אינו אמת אף למדת האינשי, שלכן החמיר למדוד במיקראסקאפ שזה שייך להחמיר לחוש לזה אף שלדינא אין מחוייבין לחשוש דסומכין על האומדנא דמומחין. ולשון שעה"צ סימן שע"ב אות י"ח הוא תמוה וברור שסומכין אף במדות [cont.]

Comment: דאורייתא כדסובר בעצמו.

Comment: What exactly are you're supposed to divide between people using Pi "*אל תסמוך בזה בחלוקת הדברים בין בני אדם"*

Comment: @AlBerko I don't understand what you're asking. Why do I attribute this discussion to a Machlokes in the Poskim? Because the way I see their words, that's what they're saying.

Comment: What money can you divide imprecisely between people using Pi? As you quoted

Comment: @Al The Chinuch gives the example of selling a field, and someone insists on buying a perfectly circular portion of the field. You have to be stringent and over-estimate if necessary, so as not to cheat the buyer. (NB: Ona'ah doesn't apply to land, so those halachos are irrelevant to the Chinuch's case.)

Comment: That π = 3 passage got a brief flash of fame again this century in science discussion. It's a great example of significant digits. If we were writing in English, the word choices suggest the possibility of measuring to one significant digit. We don't have any surviving ancient literature though to compare the meanings against so we literally can't know if that's the meaning in ancient Hebrew. The language is preserved very good, but not _that_ good.

Comment: @DonielF I'm sure this is just me being stupid but I can't find the Mishnah Maggid giving these rulings. Are you able to quote the actual passages from each of his comments on Eruvin and Shabbat that cover this? Thanks so much!

Comment: See follow up https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/115326/759

Comment: Sorry I didn’t respond more quickly; the two quotes in the follow-up are indeed the two that I’m referring to.